# If $X$ is finite dimensional, what is an explicit metric inducing the weak topology on $X?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Then weak topology on $X$ is metrizable if and only if $X$ is finite dimensional.

I have proven the forward direction, which is, if weak topology on $X$ is metrizable, then $X$ is finite dimensional.

To prove another direction, I think it suffices to prove that if $X$ is finite dimensional, then weak and norm topologies coincide, as norm topology is induced by a metric.

However, I would like to have a proof of defining a metric $d$ on weak topology explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly"? Because literally any norm you put in the space will work.

Comment: So if $X$ is finite dimensional, then any norm on it will metrizable weak topology? By explicit, I mean a formula, like $d(x,y)= |x-y|.$

Comment: There's no canonical answer, as observed by  Aloizio Macedo, but there is an psychologically obvious answer.  Weak convergence is the same as co-ordinatwise convergence (after identifying $X$ with $\mathbb C^n$), and co-ordinatewise convergence is manifestly the same as $\ell_\infty$ convergence.  (And yes, any norm will do, because in finite dimensions there is a unique convex topological vector space topology.)